# Docker Shipyard - deploying a container to a specific node

Tags: docker

I'm pretty new to Docker and Docker Shipyard - I have the Shipyard GUI running and I was wondering what parameters I need to specify in order to deploy a container to a specific node. [image]

Comment: Test with a simple Docker image: input ```nginx``` into the **Image name**, and ```80``` in both **Container Port** and **Host Port**, then press **Deploy**.

Comment: That was successful, but that doesn't get me any closer to my goal. I want to deploy to specific node. Where do I specify that? Under Swarm Constraint? Or Port Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy nginx image directly to one of my nodes. To do so, I had to speicfy 'node' in the Constraint field and 'name of node' (in my case web0) as value (see image below).

My actual underlying issue is that I am using a private repository on my main node that is not configured to be access by other nodes, but thats a discussion for another thread. Thanks Tuan for the helpful suggestion of using an official image to get things moving foward.

[image]